# Typescript seems to behaves inconsistently when defining a function that returns an interface

Tags: typescript

When I have an interface with only one field (`val`)

```
interface ValObj  {
  val: number
}
```

creating an object with another field yields an error.

```
const someObj: ValObj = {
  val: 5, 
  someStr:"hello"
}
```

But this principle isn't consistent when we return a value from a function. Defining a function to return that same interface, and returning the same object works.

```
const func: () => ValObj = 
  () => ({
    val: 5, 
    someStr: "sdf"
  })
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8sogr6)

Why does Typescript's type checking allow this? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are seeing in the first example is a product of excess property checks. Excess propeties are checked only when an object literal is directly assigned to something of a given type.

In this case:

```
const func: () => ValObj = 
  () => ({
    val: 5, 
    someStr: "sdf"
  })
```

The way typing is done is to figure out the type of the arrow function first, which is `() => { val: number, someStr: string }` and then to check if this compatible with the given function signature `() => ValObj` which it is since `{ val: number, someStr: string }` is a subtype of `ValObj`. Nowhere was the object literal **directly** assigned to `ValObj`.

You get an error if you are explicit about the return type of the arrow function:

```
const func: () => ValObj = 
  () : ValObj => ({
    val: 5, 
    someStr: "sdf"
  })
```

Comment: Interesting! I did not know there is an essential difference between `const func: FuncDefinition = (param1....)=>{...}` and `const func = (param1:ParamType ...) : ReturnType => {...}`

Comment: @BenCarp I can't think of another instance where this distinction is important. Excess property checks are essentially inconsistent, they essentially flag that a subtype  (the type with more props) is not compatible with the base type. This under OOP should be valid. It's just that it is such a common source of errors that it's better to have this flaged where it most usually not intended.

Comment: Is there any way to add the Excess property check to a regular interface so objects of that type can have only fields which are members of that interface?

Comment: @BenCarp not really, there is no  concept of `strict type` in TS. Sometimes you can so things with conditional parameters to prevent excess properties but it depends on the usecase and is only applicable when we talk about a function taking in something that could have excess properties  (not in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the return type of the inner method call. It's default to `any` change it to

```
  const func: () => ValObj =
      (): ValObj => ({
      val: 5,
      someStr: "sdf"
  })
```